# Encoding json response to csv in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to encode json into csv in python with pandas, which is supposed to be easy, but the output isn't close to right.  Example json

> {'energy': {'timeUnit': 'DAY', 'unit': 'Wh', 'measuredBy': 'INVERTER', 'values': [{'date': '2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'value': 322.0}, {'date': '2022-01-02 00:00:00', 'value': 12.0}, {'date': '2022-01-03 00:00:00', 'value': 0.0}]}}

With the following code:

```
data = r.json()

print(data)

json_object = json.dumps(data)

json_object

with open(r'\\shared\AppDev\Production\data\solaredge\import.json','w') as n:
 n.write(json_object)

df = pd.read_json(r'\\shared\AppDev\Production\data\solaredge\import.json')
df.to_csv(r'\\shared\AppDev\Production\data\solaredge\import.csv', index = None)
```

Produces

> energy
> INVERTER
> DAY
> Wh
> [{'date': '2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'value': 322.0}, {'date': '2022-01-02 00:00:00', 'value': 12.0}, {'date': '2022-01-03 00:00:00', 'value': 0.0}]

It appears the inner portion of the json hasn't been parsed at all.  I'm wondering if I am missing something obvious, I am considering just stripping most of the content out manually with string functions but that seems like there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can reduce the code here by passing the JSON string directly to pandas: `df = pd.read_json(data)`. There is no need to save it to a file first. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html for more details.

Comment: CSV and most DataFrames are flat views of data (think only 2D). JSON with nested objects introduces more dimensions. This is why the nested items seem not processed as in a flat representation they cannot be represented. You need to decide how to flatten this hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of something that processes the values column.

```
data = {'energy': {'timeUnit': 'DAY', 'unit': 'Wh', 'measuredBy': 'INVERTER', 'values': [{'date': '2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'value': 322.0}, {'date': '2022-01-02 00:00:00', 'value': 12.0}, {'date': '2022-01-03 00:00:00', 'value': 0.0}]}}
import pandas as pd
energy = pd.DataFrame(data['energy'])
pd.concat((energy.drop('values', axis=1), energy['values'].apply(pd.Series)), axis=1)
```

I am dropping the first level by making the `DataFrame` from the `'energy'` key within the dictionary. This produces a frame with `timeUnit`, `unit` and `measuredBy` value repeated for each `date`, `value` dictionary.

Next, by applying `pd.Series` we can create a new table with two columns `date` and `value`. Finally, drop the old `values` column and replace it by `date` and `value` columns. This is all done by `pd.concat`, `drop` and `apply(pd.Series)`

It should look like below:

```
    timeUnit    unit    measuredBy  date                    value
0   DAY         Wh      INVERTER    2022-01-01 00:00:00     322.0
1   DAY         Wh      INVERTER    2022-01-02 00:00:00     12.0
2   DAY         Wh      INVERTER    2022-01-03 00:00:00     0.0
```